# What JSDoc tags to use when creating objects with factory i.e. mylib.create()

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, commonjs

My CommonJS module uses a factory style object creation (.create()) and I try to have JSDoc style documentation but cannot figure out which [JSDoc](http://usejsdoc.org/) tags `@class`, `@module` etc. I should to use to do it nicely. Below you can see a simplified structure of the module.

```
var MyLib = function () {
  this.msg = 'Hello';
};

exports.create = function () {
  return new MyLib();
};

MyLib.prototype.greet = function () {
  console.log(this.msg);
};
```

The lib is used in the following way. User does not know and does not need to know anything about how the lib works behind `mylib.create()`.

```
var mylib = require('mylib');
var a = mylib.create();
a.greet(); // 'Hello'
```

Therefore my question is, how should I tag the functions to have documentation to include `mylib.create()` as a constructor, `mylib.instance.greet()` as a method and **not include** anything about `MyLib` object that is used only inside the module.

Comment: sounds like a module to me, and modules don't have constructors per se, so don't fret.

Answer (score 1):

I would say `@constructs` is what you are looking for (see also http://usejsdoc.org/tags-constructs.html).

But I would argue that should document MyLib as a class and create as a function which returns an instance of that class with a proper link (i.e. `@see`).