# Documenting "Factory Constructor" classes using jsdoc

Tags: javascript, jsdoc3

I have some classes which follow the ["Factory Constructor" pattern](http://javascript.info/tutorial/factory-constructor-pattern). These are constructed by calling the factory, not using the `new` keyword.

Example:

```
/**
 * Example "Factory Constructor" class
 * @class
 */
function MyClass() {

    return /** @lends MyClass.prototype */ {

        /** One method */
        method1: function() {  },

        /** Another Method */
        method2: function() {  }

    };

}
```

Also note that the name of the factory is the same as the name of the class (as distinct from something like a static method MyClass.create()).

My problem is that jsdoc keeps insisting on documenting that this class should be constructed with 'new', eg:

[image]

I've looked at various other questions (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28947649/what-jsdoc-tags-to-use-when-creating-objects-with-factory-i-e-mylib-create) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32548126/documenting-factories-with-jsdoc)) and blog posts (eg. [this one](http://www.randomjavascript.com/2013/01/tips-for-using-jsdoc-on-enyo-kinds-and.html)) but none of them have addressed this specific issue.

I've also tried a few variations, such as

```
/**
 * Example "Factory Constructor" class
 * @name MyClass
 * @constructs
 */
```

Outcome: results in the same output as above

Documenting MyClass as a static function like this:

```
/**
 * Example "Factory Constructor" class
 * @static
 */
```

Outcome: MyClass disappears as a class altogether and is only shown as a function, probably as you would expect.